# Generating bulk dates

Tags: node.js

I wanted to ask if anyone knows a way of generating bulk dates. I want to know about how can I generate all of the dates and times between `20130631_0000` till `20151231_2359`

The month limit is 0-12
The day limit is 0-31
and the part you see after underscore is hour and minute, the hour limit is `00` till `23` and the minute is from `00` till `59`. It's basically `YYYYMMDD_HHMM`

Few examples:

`20130810_1154`, `20140103_2357`, `20150722_1049`, `20140103_2358`, `20140103_2359`, `20140104_0000`, `20140104_0001`, `20140105_1159`, `20140105_1200`

Comment: Can you add your expected output for e.g. from `20140103_2357` till `20140105_1049` ?

Comment: Please don't post it as a comment, instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65270399/edit) your question and add the expected output there.

Comment: I already gave few examples in the post but sure, I'll edit for you.

Comment: No, you gave examples for the input - but not for your actual expected output. It's still unclear to me what your expected output is. Are you trying to create the range by increasing the start-date by one minute until you reach the end-date?

Comment: I just want to get every YYYYMMDD_HHMM between one date till another. Every single month, day, hour and minute that is available. I want to save the generated numbers to a file.

Comment: Ok, so as I said above.. you're trying to increment the given start-date by one minute until the end-date is reached, right?

Comment: Right. As I said, every single available date/time.

Comment: And in which timezone ? UTC-0?

Comment: I didn't actually think of the timezone, it doesn't matter, it should write all of the dates but it's 24 hour time system, not military.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to print each date to the console:

```js
let date = new Date(2013,6,31,0,0);
const endDate = new Date(2015,12,31,23,59);

const padWithZero = num => num.toString().padStart(2, '0');

while (date <= endDate) {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = padWithZero(date.getMonth()+1);
    const day = padWithZero(date.getDate());
    const hour = padWithZero(date.getHours());
    const minute = padWithZero(date.getMinutes());
    
    console.log(`${year}${month}${day}_${hour}${minute}`)
    
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + 60000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function convertStringToDate(date){
    var year = date.substring(0,4)
    var month = date.substring(4,6)
    var day = date.substring(6,8)
    var hour = date.substring(9,11)
    var minute = date.substring(11,13)
    
    
    return new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month), parseInt(day), parseInt(hour), parseInt(minute) )
}

function addMinute(date){
    var new_date  = date;
    new_date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+1)
    
    return new_date
}

function getDatesBetween(start_date_str, end_date_str){
    
    var start_date = convertStringToDate(start_date_str)
    var end_date = convertStringToDate(end_date_str)
    
    dates = []
    
    date = start_date
    while(date.getTime() !== end_date.getTime()){
        
        dates.push(new Date(date))
        date = addMinute(date)
    }
    dates.push(end_date)
    return dates
}


function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

function convertDateToString(date){
    var year = date.getFullYear().toString()
    var month = pad(date.getMonth().toString(),2)
    var day = pad(date.getDay().toString(),2)
    var hour = pad(date.getHours().toString(),2)
    var minutes = pad(date.getMinutes().toString(),2)
    
    return year + month + day + "_" + hour + minutes
    
    
}

var start_date_str = "20130620_1224"
var end_date_str = "20130621 1224"

dates = getDatesBetween(start_date_str, end_date_str)

formatted_dates = dates.map(convertDateToString)

console.log(dates.length)
console.log(dates[dates.length-1])

console.log(formatted_dates.length)
console.log(formatted_dates[dates.length-1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and time!